# Limit distinct count of group by

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

Suppose for simplicity that I have a table `t` with columns `id` and `value`. I can find the ids that have more than one distinct value using a query such as

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT(value)) AS count
FROM t
GROUP BY id
HAVING count > 1
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Can it be changed so that the count for each id stops as soon as more than one distinct value is found for it?

Comment: Is the question only for `COUNT > 1` or a general one (so the 1 can be replaced by some other number)?

Comment: Just `COUNT > 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this variation. In theory, it would use an `(id, value)` index to find the min and max and would not have to count the distinct values at all:

```
SELECT id
FROM t
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(value) < MAX(value) ;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that the value may not be a number. Would this still work?

Comment: If they are date/datetime/timestamps or chars, it would work fine. What is the type of `value`?

Comment: It can be a varchar.

Comment: Then, it will work.

Comment: Is this equivalent to SELECT id, MIN(value) AS a, MAX(value) as b FROM t GROUP BY id HAVING a < b?

Comment: Yeah, MySQL allows that weird syntax. They are not exactly equivalent, as yours will show 3 columns instead of 1.

Comment: Why < instead of !=?

Comment: Can the min be greater than the max?

Comment: No. I mean I know they should do the same thing, I was just curious if there was a reason, perhaps for performance, that you chose one over the other.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a try. Sorry, it may take me a day or so. Thank you!